# User cannot connect to server without VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, apache-http-server, centos

I have a CentOS WHM/cPanel server hosting serveral websites. One client is currently experiencing an issue where he cannot access his own website without using a VPN. This has been going on for at least a month now.

He has given me his IP address but when I search the apache access_log for his IP the only entry that exists is from the 5th August with a 408 error. No other entries before or after that date exist.

Is there another log I should be looking in to try to find his connections, or should this be telling me that something else is going on perhaps at his end?

Comment: What does "cannot access" mean, exactly? What happens when they try to?

Comment: Sorry they are getting a 403 error page when trying to access the website, they can still get onto their cPanel login which would make me suspect an issue caused by the website, not the server directly. But I haven't made any changes that could case this, and don't believe they have either. I would expect those 403 to still be logged by apache as well?

Comment: Apache would log them if it's the Apache serving them. If there's a reverse proxy in front of Apache, it can terminate requests before they reach it.